# how to change country name of all user in ou in windows server 2003 active direcory

Tags: windows

I want to change country code of all user existing in one OU. I am using windows server 2003 enterprises edition, in which DNS is active directory integrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a VBScript which will edit the properties of all your users in a particular OU, using this :

```
objUser.Put "c", "US"
```

Where "US" is your country.

Using something like : (sample from **VBsedit**)

```
' Modify User Account Address Attributes


Set objUser = GetObject _
    ("LDAP://cn=myerken,ou=management,dc=fabrikam,dc=com") 

objUser.Put "streetAddress", "Building 43" & _
    VbCrLf & "One Microsoft Way"
objUser.Put "l", "Redmond"
objUser.Put "st", "Washington"
objUser.Put "postalCode", "98053"
objUser.Put "c", "US"
objUser.Put "postOfficeBox", "2222"
objUser.SetInfo
```

Then you use some $var for changing specific name in the first "cn=" or just do a loop.